# Selected spinner and a button click

Tags: android, fragment, spinner

I have 2 Spinner(Dropdown list) and a Button inside fragment

`spinner1` is for Subject(ex SpinnerItem: Math, Science, English)

`spinner2` is for Quarter(ex SpinnerItem: Quarter 1,Quarter 2,Quarter 3,Quarter 4)

When user select value from `spinner1` and `spinner2` and and they click the button they should move to a new fragment with a list of names depends on what they selected from the spinners

**onCreateView**

```
public Fragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,
            false);

    // SPINNER1
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinSubject);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinQuarter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                //what to do
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //what to do

        }
    });

    // BUTTON
    Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch:
               FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SubjectandQuarter());
                ft.commit();
             break;
            }
        }   
    });   

    return view;
}
```

**XML TextView**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSubject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/subject_here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuarter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/quarter_here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

SubjectandQuarter class

```
public class SubjectandQuarterextends Fragment {


public SubjectandQuarter() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjectandquarter, container,
                  false);

      TextView tvSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
      TextView tvQuarter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuarter);

      return view;
}
```

}

I don't know if I'm doing it right. Hope someone can help me with my problem(new in android)

The output should be like(ListView):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Use `spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();` in your code

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSearch:

           String spi1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();  
           String spi2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();              

           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Spinner1 = "+spi1+" Spinner2 = "+spi2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
           SubjectandQuarter fragment = new SubjectandQuarter();
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putString("spinner1", spi1);
           bundle.putString("spinner2", spi2);
           fragment.setArguments(bundle); 
           ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
         break;
        }
    }   
});
```

and

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjectandquarter, container,
                  false);

      String spi1,spi2;
      Bundle args = getArguments();
      if (args  != null && args.containsKey("spinner1"))
           spi1 = args.getString("spinner1");

      if (args  != null && args.containsKey("spinner2"))
           spi2 = args.getString("spinner2");

      TextView tvSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
      TextView tvQuarter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvQuarter);

      tvSubject.setText(spi1); 
      tvQuarter.setText(spi2);

      return view;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to view them using `TextView` not in Toast ? look at the example in my post

Comment: `code`yourtextview1.setText(spi1);

`code`yourtextview2.setText(spi2);

Comment: @user3433054 how ? with `getActivity()` ? sorry im new

Comment: @KenHollis where is `TextView` initilization.

Comment: @KenHollis is that two `TextView` in `fragment_layout.xml` or some other

Comment: `subjectandquarter` xml

Comment: @KenHollis then post that `SubjectandQuarter.class`

Comment: @Hariharan look above

Comment: @KenHollis i edied check out

Comment: this is for SubjectandQuarter class?

Comment: @KenHollis 1 one for click. 2nd one for `SubjectandQuarter.class`

Comment: you mean the first code you made for `Fragment` and the second one for `SubjectandQuarter`

Comment: @KenHollis yes yes try it.

Comment: okay I got it. But nothing is in there even the TextView that i want to appear only Toast

Answer (score 1):

simple use this to set

```
final TextView  tvSubject= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
final TextView  tvQuarter= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuarter);
```

// then cal these textview in the spinner function

```
tvSubject.setText(spi1); 

tvQuarter.setText(spi2);
```

Comment: NO not with get activity just add these two statements. remove the toast line. you can use it as a final string.

Comment: do not forget to add two textView with value null in onCreate()

Comment: `04-04 02:53:59.982: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):  at com.droid.FragmentTwo$1.onClick(Fragment.java:58)` logcat but when I look at line 58 theres nothing wrong

Comment: Hav you defined the textview ??
 TextView TextViev1,TextView2 in the starting?

Comment: yes `final TextView tvSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);` and for Quarter

Comment: thats what I did w/o `final` I'm getting error on my tvSubject.setText(spi2); and tvQuarter.setText(spi2);

Comment: u have written the word "view" after (textview) which is wrong

Comment: I'm using onCreateView and fragments

Comment: app crashes after I click the button and selecting item in spinners

Comment: still getting error in logcat and it says line 58 `tvSubject.setText(spi1);`

Comment: @KenHollis post that `SubjectandQuarter.class`

Comment: @Hariharan look at the post above